# Include external libraries in your .aar file (a plugin for Unity)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, aar

I came across a problem while implementing an Android plugin for Unity based on EasyPermissions. The issue was due to

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions$PermissionCallbacks"
```

as the relevant classes were not packed by Android Studio into my AAR file.

I tried various ways:

- Just compile in Android Studio and hope the resulting AAR will be fine **FAIL**
- Download an AAR from jCentral and add it to Unity - **FAIL**

So finally I unzipped the EasyPlugin AAR and took the classes.jar file thats inside and added this to Unity. This **worked**. Yet its quite a manual process.

What is the tinly little bit I need to add to my gradle file to get this done automatically?

I am using:

- https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions
- Unity 2017.1 (should not matter)
- Android Studio 2.3.3
- Gradle task used: build->assemble

My Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.0.1'
    provided files('unity/classes.jar')
}
```

PS. There was a second issue when overriding UnityPlayerActivity but for that a clause *provided* instead of compile was the solution.

Comment: Where did you place the aar plugin?

Comment: in Assets/Plugins/Android (in Unity)

Comment: seems that my solution to extract the classes.jar from the aar was only partially ok. I miss the resources (R class) now :(

Comment: I've been making java plugins and haven't ran into similar issues with aar plugin.

Comment: Were you using external libraries in your plugins? I try to use https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions and its not referenced in the resulting AAR and when I try to add its AAR together with mine then Unity fails on classes.jar copy.

Comment: @Programmer - thanks for help. After you said "it just works" I did everything once again. And it seems that in my "add easypermissions.aar file to Unity Plugins directory" somehow I managed to add it in a way it was not treated as a plugin (its extension was visible in Unity Project window). When I dragged it into Unity rather than copy it behind the scenes all works. **THANKS**

Comment: No problem. Glad you fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Check above comments.

If you use an external library its enough to add its AAR into Plugins/Android directory in Unity.

For some reason I added it in a way that went unnoticed by Unity and Unity was not adding it into resulting APK file.

Comment: Hi Piotr, I'm trying to do a very similar thing with the Cast API. You can reference my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043014/chromecast-native-android-to-unity-plugin-possible-import-export-problems. I was wondering what you mean by "If you use an external library its enough to add its AAR". I've tried adding it via the explorer and via Unity and no luck, still get a class not found error. I also tried manually importing .jars and hit the same resource problem as you. Any information you can provide would be great! Thanks.